# ASP.NET Core + Docker + Expose wwwroot

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to run an ASP.NET Core application using Docker and I would like to expose the external wwwroot folder to the container, so that when I make changes to it from the outside, they are automatically available to my app. Is this possible, using volumes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you use docker run then you should do below

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/wwwroot/path/in/container <image>
```

If you use `docker-compose` then you should add below to the service

```
version: "3"
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /path/on/host:/wwwroot/path/in/container
```

If you are using this on Docker for Windows then you may have to some path translation like

```
/c/path/on/host:/wwwroot/path/in/container
```

Comment: Thanks, and how about Visual Studio 2017? It uses Docker Compose 3, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @RicardoPeres, this is part of yaml i posted, so it is for version `3` only. That why i mentioned `add below to the service`