# How to allow IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to write into C:\inetpub\wwwroot mount point

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, symlink, docker-volume

I'm creating a new Windows docker compose which uses a **microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2** image. I'm using a volume for **c:\inetpub\wwwroot** which is mapped with **C:\site\Default** on the host server.

The running ASP.Net file successfully retrieves files but files at creating/writing files. I am getting the following exception: `System.IO.IOException: 'Trying to write to forbidden path: C:\inetpub\WWWRoot\agenda.css.'`

I tried the following:

- Set full access to everyone to **C:\site\Default** on the host server
- Add all rights using icacls (see dockerfile below). Here is the output for `(Get-acl c:\inetpub\wwwroot\).Access`:

  ```
  FileSystemRights  : FullControl
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : Everyone
  IsInherited       : False
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS
  IsInherited       : False
  InheritanceFlags  : None
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : -1610612736
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS
  IsInherited       : False
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

  FileSystemRights  : FullControl
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
  IsInherited       : False
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : FullControl
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : None
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : 268435456
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

  FileSystemRights  : FullControl
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : None
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : 268435456
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

  FileSystemRights  : FullControl
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : None
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : 268435456
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

  FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : None
  PropagationFlags  : None

  FileSystemRights  : -1610612736
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

  FileSystemRights  : 268435456
  AccessControlType : Allow
  IdentityReference : CREATOR OWNER
  IsInherited       : True
  InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
  PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly
  ```
- I used ProcMon on the host server and couldn't see any entry when trying to write the file

## Docker files

docker-compose:

```
services:
  core:
    image: core
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./core/dockerfile
    volumes:
      - C:/site/Default/:c:/inetpub/wwwroot:rw
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "4020-4024:4020-4024"
    environment:
      DatabaseType: SqlServer
      ConnectionString: Server=sqldata;User ID=sa;Password=pAssword123;Database=Default;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
    depends_on:
      - sqldata

  sqldata:
    ...
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2

# Also tried the bellow command with /l
RUN icacls --% "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /t
```

Comment: Don't write there in the first place. That's the root folder for all web sites in IIS. App pool accounts aren't allowed to write tehre. The App pool account already has permissions to write to its sites' root folders

Comment: If you weaken security and allow an app pool account to write there, hacking that account's web site would allow someone to modify other web sites and apps as well.

Comment: I'm trying to dockerize an existing legacy application. I know that's not the recommended way but I need to keep doing this as a first step.

Comment: In that case you have a problem - either the application is using a hard-coded path, which means it can easily break if that path changes, or it uses bad relative paths and someone decided to just break security the first time the app crashed. Try mapping the container's `wwwroot` folder to a *different* host folder instead. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620023/asp-net-core-docker-expose-wwwroot).

Comment: The application builds a path from the wwwroot path: `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(WWWRootPath, "agenda.css"), ...)`

I tried to map to different host folder as suggested, no change...

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons `IUSR` has rights to write anywhere in the container folders (being mapped or not) except in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. IIS prevents from writing into this particular path.

I ended up creating an app which uses another physical path from the dockerfile and everything works as expected now:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2

RUN C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app \"Default Web Site/\" /physicalPath:C:\SomeOtherMountPoint
```